# Upstart for docker and setuid permissions

Tags: permissions, sudo, upstart, docker, visudo

OK, this has kept me busy for a day at least, since last night. I am trying to do something very simple: run a bash script which creates a few folders and runs a `docker` container - but **using `upstart`**. But I get permission errors:

- either permission error to create folders depending on which user it defined as `setuid`
- and in any case, I get the error `cannot enable tty mode on non tty input`

I have tried using `setuid` with user `vuvu` or just leaving it out to no avail. If I do not use `setuid` I get `cannot enable tty mode on non tty input` and if I use a user which I had set as admin, I get both that error as well as `cannot create directory 'log/1438359854': Permission denied`.

Here is my `visudo` output:

```
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
%adm    ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
vuvu    ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

and I have made the user `vuvu` part of `admin` and when it did not work as part of `adm`.

My upstart is simple:

```
description "Job docker_some_api.conf created by create_init.py"
author "create_init.py"
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]
setuid vuvu
chdir /home/myuser/Docker/docker_some_api/
script
        exec /home/myuser/Docker/docker_some_api/run.sh
end script
```

And the shell script is simple (I have dumbed down to run just ubuntu):

```
sudo docker run -t -i ubuntu
```

**Nothing seems to work and I am really frustrated by now. Can you guys help?**

Comment: `cannot enable tty mode on non tty input` is *probably* the effect of something probably asking for a password in an non-interactive shell, and failing. On the other end, you are using a lot of relative path in the shell script, which you shouldn't, unless you do an explicit `cd` in the script. --- sais so, I am not an expert in docker nor in upstart, so take this with a bit of caution.

Comment: @Rmano thanks for your insight. I think it is putting me in the right direction.

Comment: @Rmano found it.  I shouldn't have specified `-t`.

Answer (score 1):

FOUND IT!!

Problem is specifying `-t` which can never work because it's allocating a pseudo-TTY. A similar problem with systemd was [reported](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/10121) but this one was for upstart.

So changing to this was all I had to do:

```
sudo docker run -i ubuntu
```

Seems easy now, never just copy options without realizing what they do.

Comment: Hmmm.... the command line here seems identical to the old one. Shouldn't the `-t` be removed?